# Why does the Visual Basic Editor window open when I connect to my computer if it was previously open but was closed?

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

Why does the Visual Basic Editor window open when I RDP into my computer?  If I opened the VBA windows in Outlook for example, and closed it but left Outlook running, when I eventually RDP into my computer again, the VBA window is open again.  Same with Access and Excel.  The only way to fix it is to close the application completely and reopen it before disconnecting and then when I connect back to the computer through RDP only the application remains open (it does not reopen the VBA interface).  It seems like it has to do something with RDP, but that may be a red herring as I only RDP into the computer.

Comment: Not sure why it's *visible* via RDP, but the VBE doesn't actually fully close after its initial launch until the host application closes - using the `X` or Alt-Q just hides it.

Comment: Wow, never new that!  So that's it, no way to close it without closing the application?

Comment: Not as far as I know - I've never really tried that hard though.